# Three linked image that scale between devices

Tags: html, css

I need three links that you can click on. The problem is that they don't scale fro other devices. I will also need to be able to have a name for each link on top of the image, this is what I have.

```html
<div id="thumbs">
    <a id="single_image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a id="single_image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a id="single_image3" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  
 

<div id="thumbs">
    <a id="single_image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a id="single_image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <a id="single_image3" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt=""/></a>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
 
</body>
  
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Add a little CSS to scale your images.

```css
#thumbs {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  width: 33%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbs">
  <a id="single_image1" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt="" /></a>
  <a id="single_image2" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt="" /></a>
  <a id="single_image3" href="#"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/444/fff" alt="" /></a>
  <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually changed the code if you don't mind looking at it

Comment: @Max I can't see any changes. It may be because I edited your question to place your code in a snippet and the edit is still pending. I'll come back and check it later.